# stuck on cycling through multiple colors.

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to find away to alternate the background color of a div. I have 11 total colors and need to cycle through them with out having the same color show up twice in a row. I have looked at the nth-child in css with no avail end up with all the same color in a few rows. Now i am trying to do it via for loops in javascript. Does any one know of a easier way to this? I have this and its gone through many iterations. I am just stuck at this point.

```
function ColorChange(){
    var divcount = $('.time').length;
    var timediv = document.getElementsByClassName('time'); 
    var mycolors = new Array("#0066cc","#996699","#990033","#ff9933", "#99cc33","#33cc66","#009999","#6699cc", "#999999","#534741", "#663333"); 
    for(var i = 0; i<timediv.length; i++){
        for(var l = 0; l<mycolors.length;l++){
            timediv[i].style.background = mycolors[l]; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you alternating on some time interval, or simply on page refresh?

Comment: As a sidenote; I would prefer to set up the colors as CSS-classes and then just alternate between classes on the html-tag.
I think that sort of separation makes stuff clearer

Comment: first question i am alt on page refresh i have it working now using the % operator. As for css-classes i had not thought of that thanks. i may switch to that format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be effectively setting the background colour to the last colour in the list. Why not try this:

```
for( var i=0; i<timediv.length; i++) {
    timediv[i].style.backgroundColor = mycolors[i % mycolors.length];
}
```

This will cycle through the defined colours, and thanks to the `%` operator it will loop around to the start of your list if it goes past the end.

Comment: Thanks so much just before you responded i just had a break through with the % operator.

Answer (score 0):

You could  create a utility class to aid with the cycling.

Here's an example of such a class. You can pass it an array and cycle through it endlessly by calling `next()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/3Gw9C/

```
function Cycler (collection) {
    this.collection = collection;
    this.index = 0;

    this.next = function () {
        if (this.index >= this.collection.length) {
            this.index = 0;
        }
        return this.collection[this.index++];
    }
}

var mycolors = new Array("#0066cc","#996699","#990033","#ff9933", "#99cc33","#33cc66","#009999","#6699cc", "#999999","#534741", "#663333");

var cycler = new Cycler(mycolors);

for (var i = 0; i < timediv.length; i++) {
    timediv[i].style.backgroundColor = cycler.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using a mix of jquery and javascript.  So I went the jquery route

http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/NyKFf/

```
function ColorChange(){

    var count = 0;
    var mycolors = new Array("#0066cc","#996699","#990033","#ff9933", "#99cc33","#33cc66","#009999","#6699cc", "#999999","#534741", "#663333"); 
    $('.time').each(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', mycolors[count++]);
        if (count > mycolors.length) count = 0;
    });

}
```

Comment: jQuery **is** javascript.

Comment: @Bart - If someone wasn't using the jQuery library, adding jQuery just to do a simple function would be overkill.  This could have been easily done with straight javascript also.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is a pure css route:
http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/9Hbmr/

```
#colors .time:nth-child(11n) {
    background-color:#0066cc;
}
#colors .time:nth-child(11n+1) {
    background-color:#996699;
}
#colors .time:nth-child(11n+2) {
    background-color:#990033;
}
#colors .time:nth-child(11n+3) {
    background-color:#ff9933;
}
```

etc